# Airflow: dag_id could not be found

Tags: airflow

I'm running an airflow server and worker on different AWS machines.
I've synced that dags folder between them, ran `airflow initdb` on both, and checked that the dag_id's are the same when I run `airflow list_tasks <dag_id>`

When I run the scheduler and worker, I get this error on the worker:

> airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: dag_id could not be found: . Either the dag did not exist or it failed to parse. [...] Command ...--local -sd /home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/airflow_tutorial.py'

What seems to be the problem is that the path there is wrong (/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/airflow_tutorial.py) since the correct path is /home/**hadoop**/...

On the server machine the path is with ubuntu, but on both config files it's simply `~/airflow/...`

What makes the worker look in this path and not the correct one?

How do I tell it to look in it's own home dir?

**edit:**

- It's unlikely a config problem. I've ran `grep -R ubuntu` and the only occurrences are in the logs
- When I run the same on a computer with `ubuntu` as a user everything works. Which leads me to believe that for some reason airflow provides the worker with the full path of the task

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue as well. `.--local -sd` is pointing to a wrong path. Do you have any solution yet?

Comment: I found an error in my DAG. I wrongly imported a module from another dir, now its resolved.

Answer (score 20):

Adding `--raw` parameter to the `airflow run` command helped me to see what was the original exception. In my case, the metadata database instance was too slow, and loading dags failed because of a timeout. I've fixed it by:

- Upgrading database instance
- Increasing parameter `dagbag_import_timeout` in airflow.cfg

Hope this helps!

Comment: if I add '--raw' it actually runs fully and fine, otherwise it raises the exception mentioned. Also by upgrading and increaing the timeout var.

Comment: how could you do the same thing for airflow running on kubernetes?

Answer (score 6):

I'm experiencing the same thing - the worker process appears to pass an `--sd` argument corresponding to the dags folder on the scheduler machine, not on the worker machine (even if `dags_folder` is set correctly in the airflow config file on the worker).  In my case I was able to get things working by creating a symlink on the scheduler host such that `dags_folder` can be set to the same value.  (In your example, this would mean creating a symlink /home/hadoop -> /home/ubuntu on the scheduler machine, and then settings dags_folder to /home/hadoop).  So, this is not really an answer to the problem but it is a viable workaround in some cases.

Comment: This is happening even in today's Kubernetes Executor, will have to update base image and create symlink. this way it can be configured to point to right days

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the **dags_folder** parameter in config file to point explicitly to the /home/hadoop/ i.e. the desired path?

This parameter controls the location to look for dags

Answer (score 1):

1. modify dags_folder in "airflow.cfg" to the dir you want
2. using para "-sd" while listing your airflow tasks, like "airflow list_tasks yourDagName -sd /opt/airflow/dags"

both worked