# Airflow - local variable 'filename' referenced before assignment

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm having an annoying issue in airflow that keeps queuing a lot of tasks in the UI and in order to keep them running I have to restart the scheduler and the workers. My Airflow configuration is using CeleryExecutor, running in 2 workers with the help of Reddis.

I had a look to the logs in the workers and it's showing me this:

```
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]: airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: dag_id could not be found: dc2_phd_nw_5225_processing. Either the dag did not exist or it failed to parse.
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]: [2018-02-05 06:53:37,385: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-17] Command 'airflow run dc2_phd_nw_5225_processing phd_5225_stage_4_add_new_gcs_segments_to_etl_unload_C 2018-02-04T02:00:00 --local --pool dc2 -sd /home/airflow/airflow/dags/doubleclick/dc2_processing.py' returned non-zero exit status 1
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]: [2018-02-05 06:53:37,388: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-17] Task airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command[a1821a3b-5ca5-430f-84ce-eb0625a7bbca] raised unexpected: AirflowException('Celery command failed',)
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 56, in execute_command
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]:     subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 581, in check_call
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]:     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'airflow run dc2_phd_nw_5225_processing phd_5225_stage_4_add_new_gcs_segments_to_etl_unload_C 2018-02-04T02:00:00 --local --pool dc2 -sd /home/airflow/airflow/dags/doubleclick/dc2_processing.py' returned non-zero exit status 1
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 367, in trace_task
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]:     R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 622, in __protected_call__
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]:     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 59, in execute_command
Feb 05 06:53:37 ip-172-31-46-75 airflow[3656]:     raise AirflowException('Celery command failed')
```

I followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44540151/2198720) that indicates to use **--raw** after airflow run command to see the real exception and it says the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 28, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 403, in run
    print("Logging into: " + filename)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'filename' referenced before assignment
```

Has anyone has the same issue or any idea how to solve it?

Comment: It looks from the stack trace like you are on 1.8. It is probably worth checking airflow 1.9 to see if the behaviour happens there.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you switch the run command to use `--raw`, you're not still passing `--local`. The command line parser doesn't enforce this, but the code is assuming only one of those is set. As you can see for yourself, [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.1/airflow/bin/cli.py#L348) it only sets the filename variable if it raw is not passed. Then [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.1/airflow/bin/cli.py#L402) it assumes filename is set if local is set. That logic doesn't work out if both are set!

Comment: Yes it makes sense. I tried and now the error is this one: `airflow run: error: argument execution_date: invalid parse value: 'dagname'
`. Any idea?

Comment: I'm running the following command: `airflow run TASK_ID 2018-02-08T02:00:00 --raw --pool dc2 -sd /home/airflow/airflow/dags/processor/dag_test.py argument execution_date: invalid parse valueairflow run: error: argument execution_date: invalid parse value: 'dagname'
`. So instead of `--local`, I'm using only `--raw`

Comment: I assume you also passed your `dag_id` before `task_id`, but yeah that looks right and works for me with a simple DAG. Can you paste more info about your DAG?